# having application run error with python3 and flask

Tags: flask, python-3.5

I am trying to run a simple flask application with python3.5 but getting below error.

`SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined`

i have installed the latest version of flask using below command.

`RUN pip3 --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install Flask gunicorn wheel`

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least python 3.8 to use the latest flask. You need to either upgrade python or find older versions of the libraries that are compatible with your python version. If you do the later there are potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks. i updated to 3.8 and its works now.